# azure datasource throwing error in Kedro datacatalog

Tags: azure-blob-storage, kedro

I am facing error when configuring azure blob storage dataset in kedro datacatalog.

I have the dataset defined in my catalog.yml as below:

```
brand_dataset:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: "abfs://container/my_file.csv"
  credentials: my_creds
  load_args:
    sep:';'
```

When trying to access the dataset from ipython ,Facing the below error

```
DataSetError: 
unexpected unindent (core.py, line 160).
Failed to instantiate DataSet 'brand_dataset' of type `kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.csv_dataset.CSVDataSet`.
```

I followed the document
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/05_data/01_data_catalog.html
particularly example:15
could not figure out why the error is?
I am working with kedro from inside docker container.

Answer (score 0):

two quick questions:

1. What version of Kedro are you running? There was an older version where we were giving an unhelpful error message.
2. Have you installed pandas in your environment? Kedro itself doesn't ship with pandas - we don't want to force it on people and want to distribute the smallest possible version. We have instructions for installing pandas here:

https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/04_kedro_project_setup/01_dependencies.html#workflow-dependencies

I suspect this is what's going on and that you need to do `pip install "kedro[pandas]"`

Comment: I am using kedro version 0.17.5. I have pandas installed using requriements.txt.
This problem is really happening when i add `adlfs` library to my requirements.txt in my docker image. But i can pip install `adlfs` inside the container later and kedro is working normally. I need `adlfs` to work with azure blob storage source files